# What does Visual Studio on mac use to host web apps locally?

Tags: macos, visual-studio

When you run/debug a web app in Visual Studio on Windows, VS temporarily hosts/serves that web app in IIS express. You can click on its tray icon and view apps currently being hosted. You can stop/start them etc.

What does Visual Studio on Mac use to host/serve web apps? And how can I access this mini web server in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ASP.NET Core web projects, VS for Mac uses Kestrel directly, since there isn't IIS Express/IIS on macOS.

Note that you can configure VS for Windows to use Kestrel directly as well.