# HTTP Error 431 on local machine in a C# MVC application

Tags: c#, http-headers, visual-studio-mac

I'm getting an HTTP Error 431 in a C# MVC application in a View after ajax sends data to my controller.  This is the code in my View:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveElectionData")",
        dataType: "text",
        data: { 'formData': sendData },
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("back in view, success");
            $("form").submit();
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert("back in view, fail");
            $("form").submit();
        }
 });
```

When I run the application, the ajax sends data to my controller.  The controller processes the data and returns a string to the ajax.  I get the alert `back in view, success`.  As soon as I click the button to close the alert, I get the 431 error.

When I look at dev tools and look at network, this is what I see:

[image]

And when I click on `Updated` this is what I see:

[image]

I am running this on a development machine (a mac) running Visual Studio 2022 and I assume IIS Express (provided by Visual Studio unless its different on a mac as opposed to a windows machine) and I had just cleared out the browser (chrome) cookies.  Also, according to the second image, the content length of the request header is only 182.

And this is the code in the view for the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Updated", "OnlineEnrollment", FormMethod.Post))
{
}
```

I do not have any elements in the form since the ajax has already sent the data to the controller.

So why would I be getting this 431 error?

Any ideas?

EDIT 1:

This is the code in my program.cs file looks like:

```
 namespace AccuRecordV3
 {
    public class Program
    {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
       }

       public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
                {
                    options.Limits.Http2.MaxRequestHeaderFieldSize = 40960;
                });
            });

    }

 }
```

Comment: Visual Studio on Mac doesn't use iisexpress, and no-one seems prepared to say [what it does use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63852764/what-does-visual-studio-on-mac-use-to-host-web-apps-locally). My guess is apache, though, for what it's worth. Anyway, could it be something to do with cookie size? I realise you said you cleared them, but there seem to be a lot of cookies in your first image.

Comment: @stuartd - I’m not creating any cookies so those must be generated by visual studio, maybe? I am using TempData but i believe that data stays on the server

Comment: Can you please post the code for the applicable model, view, and controller? I had a similar error that was caused by using TempData.

Comment: @keipala There must be some limit on TempData.  I reworked some of my code and reduced the amount of data being placed into TempData and this error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the network tab, then you will see actually it is Kestrel that returns this 413 response along with the message "Request Header Fields Too Large".

There are quite a few options you can configure there, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0 and `MaxRequestHeadersTotalSize` should be the one you need.

Comment: I read the article you provided.  I edited my program.cs file to include the MaxRequestHeadersTotalSize parameter and provided it a value of 8196.  It still fails.   So I increased the number to 40960.  That fails as well.  Any other suggestions?